# Framework for testing Dojo

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, javascript

I need to automate tests for Liferay portal with portlets on JavaScript. I am going to try several frameworks before implementing tests. For now, I am considering [D.O.H.](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/util/doh.html) and Selenium Webdriver. Selenium because I know it and we implemented a lot of testing using it and [D.O.H.](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/util/doh.html) because it seems it is made for Dojo.

Are there any other frameworks worth considering? I'd like to hear about frameworks that offer the following functionality:

1. Ability to wait AJAX requests
2. Save results in database
3. Generate reports and send them to email
4. It should work on Linux
5. Ability to write scripts in some programming language (Python, Java, JavaScript, Ruby)

I know that Selenium itself, for example, doesn't save results and create reports. But it may be that there are useful frameworks that can do that.

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on GUI testing tools.

Comment: Ilia, perhaps you could elaborate a little. What factors would cause you to pick one framework over the other? We could make giant lists of frameworks to use, but that's not really how questions are supposed to go here. Preferably, there's enough information to give a definitive, objective answer instead of "I like blah, try it" or something similar.

Comment: I have no time to go through all frame works in Wiki. I'm going to try several frameworks before implementing tests. So I choose two for now: Selenium because I know it and we implemented a lot of testing using it and DOH because it seems it is made for Dojo. 
And now I ask: may be someone has used another frameworks that will be useful for Dojo+Liferay testing.

Comment: If you don't have time to go through generic lists, then you're unlikely to get useful info without giving a little bit more information. Corsika's right - if you can say a little bit more about what would help you pick a framework it'll help people be more specific than Wikipedia. You've given two more bits of info in your comment - you already know Selenium, and you're interested in frameworks meant for Dojo. Anything else that's important to you?

Comment: I need the following:
1. ability to wait AJAX requests
2. Save results in database
3. Generate reports and sent them to email
4. It should work on Linux
5. Ability to write scripts on some programming language (Python, Java, JavaScript, Ruby)

Comment: I know that Selenium itself, for example, doesn't save results and create reports. But may be there are useful  frameworks to do that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the additional info. I added it into your question, and I've tweeted the link in the hope that it'll get a few more views (and some answers!) for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a reasonable list, but people tend to solve these problems by glueing different frameworks together.  In particular, saving results to a database, generating reports, and sending emails may be well-served by Jenkins.

Selenium has APIs for a number of languages -- I assume that is the part you want to script.

Virtually any open-source testing framework will run on Linux, except perhaps for those that are for testing software that is operating system specific.